# Error response from daemon: Container is not running Bamboo

Tags: python, docker, bamboo, docker-image

I am trying to build and run docker image through bamboo.
I could successfully build the image. But, while run got the below error:

```
Error response from daemon: Container eb5c9788d214a10cfe208cada067bc7721981d30c3dadfe84bb7857c55f9fa97 is not running

Error occurred while running Task 'Run docker Container(9)' of type com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-docker-plugin:task.docker.cli.
```

Comment: Two questions: Did you push the image into a repository or did you just build it? Are you using a script or the built-in Docker Bamboo tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart the service of the docker, by using this

sudo service docker restart

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth investigating the container state with an interactive docker session, in our case it turned out to be an update to a container that exited unexpectedly.